# find the rows by unique id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table stude in following form

TABLE STUD

```
S_ID | CL_ID |
1    | ABCD  |
2    | ABCD  |
3    | ASDF  |
4    | QWEI  |
5    | ZXXC  |
6    | ZXXC  |
6    | XZDR  |
1    | XZXR  |
3    | EWDF  |
```

and i want to extract the rows form this table with unique s_id and any of CL_ID associated to it.

output can be like:

```
S_ID | CL_ID |
1    | XZXR  |
2    | ABCD  |
3    | ASDF  |
4    | QWEI  |
5    | ZXXC  |
6    | XZDR  |
```

Please help me to write query on this.

Comment: Any CL_ID - you intentionally don't want this to be deterministic? Or you do you have criteria to prefer one value over another? (Alphabetic order, some other column in the table, ...)

Comment: i do not have any preference, i can have any of the cl_id values

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT S_ID, MIN(CL_ID)
FROM STUD
GROUP BY S_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
  from your_table
 where rowid in (select min(rowid) from your_table group by s_ID)
```

Comment: what is rowid here? i tried by s_id and it did not work.

Comment: @RosAng What did you try by `s_id`?